How to create and sign a segwit transaction using any npm pacakge
So I am using this NPM package ( https://www.npmjs.com/package/bitcore-lib )
to create and sign a Bitcoin legacy transaction locally and it was working fine for legacy.
But when I tried to do the same for segwit addresses I started getting this error when i submit that raw into sendrawtransasction node method.
mandatory-script-verify-flag-failed (Witness requires empty scriptSig)

So I think the issue is with this package as the structure of this payment is not what is required for a SegWit transaction.
So my main question is is there any package in javascript I can use to create and sign a transaction? the main payload I have is
receipentAddress, senderAddress, amount ( in satoshis ), and privateKey in WIF. 

any help or clue is highly appreciated.
//edit:
rawhex:
02000000017d155e9418b60ee26fe189d4381a1fcd5aac1d8eed5216c210e6f6e7a6d86b37010000006a47304402204d6b08238b2eafbf18b7b940a4bbb59c1cc610a1d5e05d2ed72f78f9a6035b890220513a33b2461f12f711776063a54d62913adef76eb40f62ad0eac3f16577c572e01210312bc181f50c9dff7d5ebe77d4df32a9ae2e5b0530b5a4a9c4b8b88647911a883ffffffff029065000000000000160014dc804b4f932f37f77ff9a4f843c845dc3cc3d30164f20300000000001600149518ea8b88e82e82d9003fa3f7518e15180cc58500000000

edit: added code below
const axios = require('axios');
const bitcore = require('bitcore-lib');

async function generateAndSignTransaction(payload) {
  let { address, privateKey, recipientAddress, satoshis, chain } = payload;

  try {
    async function fees() {
      try {
        let key;
        if (chain === "testnet"){
          key = 'test3'
        }else {
          key = 'main'
        }

        let r = await axios.get(`https://api.blockcypher.com/v1/btc/${key}`);
        let feeObj = new Object;
        feeObj["High_fee"] = r.data.high_fee_per_kb;
        feeObj["Medium_fee"] = r.data.medium_fee_per_kb;
        feeObj["Low_fee"] = r.data.low_fee_per_kb;
        return feeObj;
      } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        throw error; // Propagate error
      }
    }


    let res = await fees();
    let fee = res.Low_fee;


    let url = `https://blockstream.info/${chain}/api/address/${address}/utxo`;
    res = await axios.get(url);

    console.log('UTXOS: ', res.data);


    let i = 0;
    let utxos = [];
    let balance_utxos = 0;

    while (balance_utxos <= satoshis + fee && i < res.data.length) {
      let utxo = {
        "txId": res.data[i].txid,
        "outputIndex": res.data[i].vout,
        "script": bitcore.Script.buildPublicKeyHashOut(address).toString(),
        "satoshis": res.data[i].value
      };
      utxos.push(utxo);
      balance_utxos += res.data[i].value;
      i++;
    }
    console.log('UTXOS 02: ', utxos);

    let tx = new bitcore.Transaction();
    tx.from(utxos);
    tx.to(recipientAddress, satoshis);
    tx.change(address);
    tx.fee(fee);
    tx.inputs.forEach(input => {
      input.setScript(bitcore.Script.empty());
    });
    tx.sign(privateKey);


    console.log('Tramsactopnm: ', tx);
    console.log('Tramsactopnm data: ', tx.serialize());

    let txnHex = tx.toString();

    return { txid: txnHex }; // Return the serialized transaction
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error:', error);
    throw error; // Propagate error
  }
}


module.exports = { generateAndSignTransaction };


From error message, I guess you sign your transaction in a same way when spend legacy address, because it literally means your script sig is not empty(it must be empty for segwit spend as script sig must be placed into witness stack). I don't think it would be problem with bitcore-lib, but you might use my open source bitcoin-sdk-js as an alternative as it supports segwit spend.
Below code works.
import * as bitcoin from 'bitcoin-sdk-js';

const privkey =
  'e6c58327b4bf1314296bba7adb66f94c36ea5611ac07830c229aa7ee6f9caac3';
const toAddress = 'tb1qmjqyknun9umlwlle5nuy8jz9ms7v85cp7k2nfe';
const toValue = 300000;
const txHash =
  '8bcd197873dbff5cc67cb3e0b1cbbdf097c7af94b0e9365adecb424e408294bf';
const inputValue = 310981;

const tx = new bitcoin.Transaction();

await tx.addInput({
  txHash: txHash,
  index: 1,
  value: inputValue,
});
await tx.addOutput({
  address: toAddress,
  value: toValue,
});
await tx.signInput(privkey, 0);

const txHex = await tx.getSignedHex();



here is the raw hex
02000000017d155e9418b60ee26fe189d4381a1fcd5aac1d8eed5216c210e6f6e7a6d86b37010000006a47304402204d6b08238b2eafbf18b7b940a4bbb59c1cc610a1d5e05d2ed72f78f9a6035b890220513a33b2461f12f711776063a54d62913adef76eb40f62ad0eac3f16577c572e01210312bc181f50c9dff7d5ebe77d4df32a9ae2e5b0530b5a4a9c4b8b88647911a883ffffffff029065000000000000160014dc804b4f932f37f77ff9a4f843c845dc3cc3d30164f20300000000001600149518ea8b88e82e82d9003fa3f7518e15180cc58500000000
and the error is
mandatory-script-verify-flag-failed (Witness requires empty scriptSig),
checking on this pkg, will keep you updated.

As I guessed you are trying to spend segwit output in a legacy way(which is wrong). You must move script sig part(which is 47304402204d6b08238b2eafbf18b7b940a4bbb59c1cc610a1d5e05d2ed72f78f9a6035b890220513a33b2461f12f711776063a54d62913adef76eb40f62ad0eac3f16577c572e01210312bc181f50c9dff7d5ebe77d4df32a9ae2e5b0530b5a4a9c4b8b88647911a883) to witness stack(at the end of tx hex) and also need to add segwit flag, mark and witness item count. I think the signature itself would be also wrong as the segwit message to sign is different from legacy. You can check BIP143 for specific semantic.

brother, i dont understand all these that much, I just want a tool or pacakge to work, and i will only provide the payload which is
{
address: 'tb1qj5vw4zugaqhg9kgq873lw5vwz5vqe3v9uldtdu',
privateKey: 'L4xJPRKG4QpqeFraSqJQiY6iPd364H8E9jrmtZkqVw2WQVCejBcj',
recipientAddress: 'tb1qmjqyknun9umlwlle5nuy8jz9ms7v85cp7k2nfe',
satoshis: 26000,
chain: 'testnet'
}
and the code should give me hex which works. the package you shared doesn't have a proper doc, and code is also outdated. anyways I'll try to make it work. thanks for the time.

I'm sorry I just pushed tx to testnet for test accidentally with the private key you provided and it works well. I edited my answer with code.
If you need testnet btc let me know I will send to you.

Hi Hyunhum, that's really great that this code works I also want to try this but i have nothing left unspent, i have tried many faucets but haven't received any yet, can you please send me back?

I have tried this code although not sure about how you fetched priv key from wif, i have used bitcoinjs-lib for that, the hex it generates is giving me bad-txns-inputs-missingorspent
error, hex is: 010000000001017d155e9418b60ee26fe189d4381a1fcd5aac1d8eed5216c210e6f6e7a6d86b370100000000fdffffff0190650000000000001600149518ea8b88e82e82d9003fa3f7518e15180cc58502483045022100d4f0c6e6b5fdca9839a3a75f1f9daaa6c9d083c57bd731d6a78f0d5f448bc6de02205015a6b67abde663f7772e4c499e43ad920de5d4ac447c274ceb49bcfcb53be8012103cc5b73e26e04b2e9cb71723f7669ff611127e219fd14ad522c649272faef8a7500000000

because that tx is already broadcasted by me(in other words it is spent). I will send u test btc. u can try with unspent transaction

No actully I have now tried with difftrent account where the utxo is left, but still get this error.

No you didn't have utxo left as you can see https://blockstream.info/testnet/address/tb1qj5vw4zugaqhg9kgq873lw5vwz5vqe3v9uldtdu
I sent you same amount in transaction id 8bcd197873dbff5cc67cb3e0b1cbbdf097c7af94b0e9365adecb424e408294bf, try using this

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

I have tried it with this account also it sends me a hex:
010000000001017d155e9418b60ee26fe189d4381a1fcd5aac1d8eed5216c210e6f6e7a6d86b370100000000fdffffff01803e000000000000160014dc804b4f932f37f77ff9a4f843c845dc3cc3d30102473044022048f3104cb19a1f2f61cae8c40a6f6d7ec1d9bbb117a918533e852bfc54b6eaab022077c24324009bae1db18ed73c1e4c5fe03d54a2c89e63ff58fb4839fb7829d36d01210312bc181f50c9dff7d5ebe77d4df32a9ae2e5b0530b5a4a9c4b8b88647911a88300000000
and when I pass this in node method sendrawtransaction it returns {"bad-txns-inputs-missingorspent"} error. can you please help me to debug this, thanks
